# How to refresh window inside the idle function in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Im using GLUT and i need to refresh a draw inside the idle function, my code is something like that:

```
void idle(){

     for(int i ;i<cant;i++){

          /* do some stuff*/

          glutPostRedisplay();
     }
}
```

inside the idle function proccess de data what i want to redraw in every itaration.

Someone can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800512/how-to-update-glut-window-continuously - anyway, don't "block indefinitely" in idle and only post a redraw once at the end. The glut application is still single-threaded so the redraw won't be called until the idle function returns. It is a "post re-display after this function".

Comment: thank for your answer, i move the loop inside the display function and use de swapbuffer function to draw the image in every iteration.

Comment: Err, that's a similar problem - blocking one of 'stages' in the glut design.

Answer (score 3):

Do *one* (or few) things in idle, then postRedisplay.
Let the timer (calling idle) do the loop !

you should ensure than the computation load of idle + redisplay is largely less than the timer rate you required (or the FPS you expect).